# Origin of the Latin Language?

Tags: history, proto-indo-european, etruscan

> Latin is an Italic language which originated in the Italian peninsula, and was originally spoken in Latium and Ancient Rome located along the Mediterranean Sea. Similar to most European languages, Latin is a descendant of the ancient Proto-Indo-European language

I also read it has been heavily influenced by the Etruscan language.

But  do we have records of the Proto-Latin, or is it only suppositions based on the philological study of common Indo-European and the Latin words?

How Proto-Latin looked like? From what Proto-Latin came?

Answer (score 13):

In the beginning, there was…well, we're not really sure. The origins of language are lost to time. But *at some point*, there was Proto-Indo-European, the hypothetical reconstructed ancestor of all the later Indo-European languages. As the Indo-European people spread across the continent, the dialects they spoke started to diverge; one of these dialects (spoken in western Europe) became Proto-Italo-Celtic, then the southern part of that became Proto-Italo-Venetic (or "Greater Proto-Italic"), then the southern part of *that* became Proto-Italic (or "Lesser Proto-Italic").

But all of this, so far, is purely theoretical. Linguists have a pretty good understanding of what Proto-Italic looked like, but it's all reconstructed by comparing the daughter languages against each other—there's no actual written record of Proto-Italic. (Some linguists in fact only use the "Proto-" prefix for reconstructions: if we actually found some inscriptions in this language, it would be called "Common Italic" instead. But this convention isn't universal.)

Then, starting around the seventh century BCE, the situation changes. The Italic-speaking peoples have picked up writing from the Etruscans and/or Greek colonists in Magna Graecia, and inscriptions start to show up! So from this point, we have a pretty clear picture of what the different languages in the vicinity of Rome looked like: Italic had split into two branches, the *Sabellic* or *Eastern Italic* languages (like Oscan and Umbrian) and the *Latino-Faliscan* or *Western Italic* languages (Latin and Faliscan). And underlying all of them was a substrate of Etruscan, a completely unrelated language that had been spoken there before the Italic-speakers had moved in.

The Latin of the earliest inscriptions is generally called *Old Latin*, and is the oldest stage of the language that we have direct evidence for. Anything earlier, like Proto-Italic, has been reconstructed by comparing Latin and Faliscan and Oscan and Umbrian and so on to find the core similarities between them. And Old Latin, as a blanket term, covers everything from the Praenestine Fibula (seventh century BCE) to the mid-first century BCE. The oldest parts look quite a bit different from Classical Latin, but they're much more similar to Classical than Classical is to, say, modern Italian.

P.S. You mention Etruscan influence on Latin—there was definitely some influence, but it's not as huge as one might expect. The biggest effects I can think of are initial stress/medial vowel reduction and a bunch of loaned vocabulary, but not much else. Though it's hard to say for sure, given how little we know about Etruscan in general.

Comment: How much loaned vocabulary from Etruscan is "a bunch"? Is it comparable to the amount of medieval French that got absorbed into English?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Much, much less. I don't have a good numerical answer, but I'd think it's closer to the amount of, say, _modern_ French loaned into English.

Answer (score 7):

The question might be better suited for [Linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/). However, the general information on the history of Latin is outlined in the Wikipedia article of the [same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Latin):

"It is believed that the earliest surviving inscription is a seventh-century B.C. pin known as the [Praenestine fibula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praenestine_fibula), which reads Manios med fhefhaked Numasioi "Manius made me for Numerius"."

[image: right to left]
*The writing above runs from right to left.*
…

"**Vulgar Latin** […]
This spoken Latin differed from the literary language of Classical Latin in its grammar and vocabulary. […] Because there are few phonetic transcriptions of the daily speech of these Latin speakers (to match, for example, the post-classical [Appendix Probi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appendix_Probi)) Vulgar Latin must be studied mainly **by indirect methods**.
Knowledge of Vulgar Latin comes from a variety of sources. First, the **comparative method** reconstructs items of the mother language from the attested Romance languages. Also, prescriptive grammar texts from the Late Latin period condemn some usages as errors, providing insight into how Latin was actually spoken. […]"

So, not only do we **not** have any records of [Proto-Italic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Italic_language), the language that evolved into Latin and other [Italic languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italic_languages). In fact, there are no  records of the actual Latin pre-dating the 7th century BC and thus all this knowledge is indeed based on the scientific reconstruction.

**Edit:**
A comment on "Praenestine fibula" can be found in [The Latin Language](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=O7z4Sl-SgFEC&lpg=PA60&ots=rNKm0w1wcw&dq=Numasioi&pg=PA60#v=onepage&q=Numasioi&f=false) by [Leonard Robert Palmer](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwizp8m_oO3lAhWILMAKHZqAA0AQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLeonard_Robert_Palmer&usg=AOvVaw2ue3SeYPzzU8Wgwb-IWR0v):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the community, @tum_!

Comment: @vectory Cheers, added the image you suggested + an excerpt from "The Latin Language".

Comment: I only meant they didn't use Roman Latin font.

Comment: @vectory I understood. The added excerpt says 'inscribed in Greek characters' (though, I struggle to recognise many of them). The Roman Latin is used in the quote from Wikipedia, for some reason someone decided to 'transliterate' the phrase this way...